# Does Peach's float negate shorthop knockback multipliers?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

Someone told me that Peach's float allows her to quickly perform full-strength aerials close to the ground in a short hop-like situation. Is this actually the case?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Yes. If Peach (or Daisy) Float, they’re not affected by the Short Hop Modifier

[@MBorg's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/351991/222207) is right on the money. But I'd like to supplement it with some visuals:

Like they explain, for all characters, any aerial performed out of a shorthop will have a .85x damage modifier attached to it. For example, with an un-staled Ganon down-air performed from both a short and full hop:

[image: Ganon sh dair]
[image: Ganon fh dair]

<sup>(for those of you at home, 23.9 x .85 = 20.315 = ~20.3)</sup>

But with Peach, as MBorg has noted, things are a little different...

Here's an un-staled Peach back-air from a short hop, full hop and then a float (please forgive my terribad video editing):

[image: Peach sh bair]
[image: Peach fh bair]
[image: Peach float bair]

Notice how--while the short hop deals only 12.8%--both the full hop and float clock in at the same amount of damage: 15.1%!

This is something I've seen many players in the community clamoring about nerfing. It's a disadvantage everyone has except Peach! While less damage means less knockback (given the way [knockback operates](https://www.ssbwiki.com/knockback#Formula)) which means potentially more combos, Peach already has some devastating 0-80% combos with her float as they are!

<strike>With Balance Patch 3.1.0 dropping any day now, we'll see if this gets touched...</strike>

[Patch 3.1.0 is live!](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/45405/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNTU5MjY0NDQ0L2dlbi8xNTU5MjY0NDQ0L3NpZC9mVXFsX29QVUFJalNna010YjNYeVYyb3BOeWVoWjhKaXQ3THBXMld6SmtzUW1URjFyVGV3bDZmYWslN0VNN2ZVVzYlN0UlN0VrcG9DWDlQOG5rcExENnlaQ2dacmZMWlF0JTdFV0ZXN0g5ZmpubUJkbDklN0VuWEIyZzJ4VlU1OUlBJTIxJTIx) While Peach received several nerfs, her float wasn’t touched, so all of the above still stands.

Comment: I suppose the real question should be "Why does Ganondorf's down air deal 23.9% damage?"

Answer (score 13):

To clarify, the [short hop multiplier does not directly change knockback.](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/abypth/psa_all_aerials_do_less_damage_on_short_hop/) Instead, it [lowers the damage of short hop aerials by 15% (to 85%).](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/8zffsv/ruben_smash_ultimate_introduces_a_new_damage/) The knockback is only reduced because it's calculated after the damage, and opponents with less damage get knockbacked less. This is only a small reduction in knockback.

Back to your question, [yes, Peach's (and Daisy's) float negates this multiplier.](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Peach_(SSBU)) This makes Peach's (and Daisy's) aerials relatively more damaging and with greater shieldstun. They can be performed anywhere in the air, [including close to the ground as per this demonstrative video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0T374Zf7LY&t=335s) [This same video later](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0T374Zf7LY&t=360s) highlights the potency of these aerials' increased damage and shieldstun through combos that rack up damage quickly and imply strong shield pressure.